# Iterating while constructing immutable object in Scala

Tags: scala, for-loop, immutability

I have a library class which I can't change:

```
class MultiPart {
  private val _parts: Seq[Part] = Seq.empty[Part])

  def addHead(head: Head): MultiPart = Multipart(_parts :+ head)

  def addPart(part: Part): MultiPart = Multipart(_parts :+ part)
}
```

In my code, I want to construct an immutable object of class Multipart, while iterating in a for loop.
But I am not able to figure out how to do that.
My current code looks like :

```
var mp: MultiPart = new MultiPart().addHead(head)
arrParts.foreach(x => mp.addPart(x))
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It seems you want a `foldLeft`/`foldRight`.

Comment: If you want it immutable, why don't you just create a new `MultiPart` with new `Seq[Part]`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should use foldLeft or foldRight (similar functions in other languages are usually called reduce)

```
arrParts.foldLeft(new MultiPart().addHead(head))(
    (list, part) => {
        list.addPart(part)
    }
)
```

There's some good examples on this page if you're confused: http://oldfashionedsoftware.com/2009/07/30/lots-and-lots-of-foldleft-examples/